# Uniqueidentifier in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can I do some thing like this in MySQL? I want to have a unique id generate by the database automatically but not using auto_increment.

```
CREATE TABLE cust(
     CustomerID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT newid(),
     Fax varchar(15) NULL
);
```

I have try this, but there has an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT newid(), Fax varchar(15) NULL )' at line 2`

Comment: I highly recommend let it as `AUTOINCREMENT` not null

Comment: Just make sure to designate `CustomerID` as a PKEY in your table so that WHEN (not IF) an ID ever dupes then the INSERT will fail by default

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUID() to create a Unique Value.

Eg.

```
INSERT INTO cust (CustomerID, Fax) Values(UUID(), "21312312");
```